# Why the exception is not caught?

Tags: c++, c++builder-10.4-sydney

Can somebody tell me why, in the code below, the exception is never caught? It always stops the program after attempting to execute the SQL command, throwing an Oracle server exception. I am using Devart UniDAC components in the Community Editon of C++Builder.

```
UniConn1->StartTransaction();
try
{
    Query1->Execute();
    UniConn1->Commit();
}
catch(Exception  *E)
{
    if (E->Message.Pos("ORA-0001" ) > 0)
        Application->MessageBox(L"Interrupção já cadastrada!",
                                    Application->Title.c_str(),
                                    MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK);
    else
        Application->MessageBox(E->Message.c_str(),
                                    Application->Title.c_str(),
                                    MB_ICONERROR+MB_OK);
    UniConn1->Rollback();
}
```

Comment: Catch exceptions by reference, not by pointer, eg: `catch(const Exception &E)`

Comment: Hi Remy, thank you for the English corrections. I used to be better. It's been a long time I do not use English.

Comment: I have changed the code to catch errors by reference, the application still is not catching the errors. The only way I've found was putting code on the OnError of the connection component.

Comment: that would imply the components are not throwing an exception inside the scope of your `try` block to begin with.

Comment: Yes, I suspect it too. I have asked the same question on the components forum, but I've got no answer till now

Comment: Which compiler are you using? If one of the CLang-based compilers, it might be possible that the compiler doesn't realize the code could throw an exception, and so ignores the `catch`. See [Differences Between Clang-enhanced C++ Compilers and Previous-Generation C++ Compilers: Try Blocks Cannot Handle Some Exceptions](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Differences_Between_Clang-enhanced_C%2B%2B_Compilers_and_Previous-Generation_C%2B%2B_Compilers#Try_Blocks_Cannot_Handle_Some_Exceptions). Just a guess.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy. Your last comment has solved the question. After I set up the compiler to use Borland's Classic compiler the try-catch block began to work.

Answer (score 1):

To handle exceptional situations in higher versions of RAD Studio using the method you provided, use the classic Borland compiler:
Project Options\Building\C++ Compiler\C++ Compilers\Use 'classic' Borland compiler

Comment: I have already set up the compile method to use the classic Borland compiler, until now no exception was raised. I will make an sql error to check if it is working. At this point the application do not have any SQL error.